# Synergy One-to-Many Keymapping

Tags: ubuntu, osx, keyboard-shortcuts, configuration, synergy

## Overview

I'm trying to map both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> on Ubuntu
to <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on MacOS.

## Progress

So far, I have only been able to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **or** <kbd>Alt</kbd>,
but not both.

## Attempted Strategies

In my `.synergy.conf` on the host (Ubuntu), I have tried the following:

1. Valid syntax, wrong results (only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), expected success:

   ```
   section: screens
     desktop:
     mac:
       ctrl = meta
       super = alt
       super = ctrl
   ```
2. Invalid syntax, reasonable strategy, expected success:

   ```
   section: screens
     desktop:
     mac:
       ctrl = meta
       super = ctrl, alt
   ```
3. Valid syntax, wrong results (only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), didn't expect success:

   ```
   section: screens
     desktop:
       alt = super
     mac:
       ctrl = meta
       super = ctrl
   ```
4. Invalid syntax, reasonable strategy, didn't expect success:

   ```
   section: screens
     desktop:
     mac:
       ctrl = meta
       super = (ctrl, alt)
   ```

## Documentation

I have failed to find helpful [existing answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206867/synergy-between-mac-and-pc-change-mac-hotkeys), U&L SE, or elsewhere. I also read the [official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto).